# In C#, How can I deserialize this result I am getting from a REST service?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I am getting this string  result back from a rest service:

```
Test: [[]] MessageDetail: [['{"Field1": "Value1", "Field2": "Value2", "BM Fields": "{\'BM Field 1\': \'BM Value 1\', \'Field2\': \'\'}", "Field 2": "Value 4"}']]
```

and unfortunately only the data inside the "MessageDetail" tag is valid json (which i will send to a json deserializer) so i trying to figure out the best way to remove the unnecessary part of the message.  So i want to parse out the string inside the message which I can

```
{"Field1": "Value1", "Field2": "Value2", "BM Fields": "{\'BM Field 1\': \'BM Value 1\', \'Field2\': \'\'}", "Field 2": "Value 4"}
```

what is the best way to strip out the first part of the string before the first apostrophe as well as the last part of the string after the last apostrophe so I can just get what is listed in the second section above?

Comment: Can you just remove `Test: [[]] MessageDetail:` from the string?

Comment: @Love - its not always that exact string but its more about getting rid of the info before the first {

Comment: Why your rest api returning a valid json?

Comment: @Savaratkar - I don't control this so unfortunately not an option

Comment: If you dont have valid json and dont know the pattern of unwanted string there is no way you can deserilize it , you need to have valid json. So either ask the provider to return valid json or tell you how you can extract valid json.

Comment: The data inside the "Message Detail" IS Valid json.  i just need to remove the stuff before and after

Comment: Have you considered using Jackson JS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this by using both Substring and IndexOf, considering you want to use the "{" as a reference

```
string output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("{")+1,input.Length-2)
```

This code only intends to omit the "{" and "}"

After this just use your JSON parser on output

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: using string remove function

```
string output = input.Remove(startIndexOfApostrophe, count);
```

Step 2:
    In Visual Studio, paste special as Json to generate the classes

Step 3:
    [Deserializing json](http://www.codetrench.com/deserializing-json-resources-with-c-sharp-and-json-net/)

Comment: as per my comment to @Love - its not always that same exact string so i can't do a hard coded string replace

Comment: You can use [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of replace.

Comment: I would lovely like to hear the opinion of downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write exact code, but can give you right algo since am typing from mobile:

```
Var array = result.split('[[');
Var json = array.last();
json = json.replace(']]', '');
```

Send this 'json' variable for deserialization.

Comment: Better solution wud b to write regular expression to get content inside [[]]. And am not good with regex